# How can I use std::for_each with boost::bimap?

Tags: c++, boost

I have a boost::bimap and I want to iterate over all positions
to add the values of the given side to another STL-compatible container.
How can I do this?

My approach was to use std::for_each together with boost::bind:

```
std::for_each(mybimap.left.begin(),
              mybimap.left.end(),
              boost::bind(&vector::push_back, &myvec,
                boost::bind( ... )));
```

Comment: And it does not work because... (put error description here)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work:

```
  std::for_each(mybimap.left.begin(),
                mybimap.left.end(),
                boost::bind(&vector_type::push_back, &myvec,
                   boost::bind(&map_type::left_map::value_type::second, _1)));
```

... or if you mean the key values mapped from instead of the values being mapped to, use `first` instead of `second`.

**EDIT:** I find this double-bind rather clumsy, and the `for_each` a non-optimal algorithm (`copy` would be better suited, IMHO the algorithm name should state the intent and that's clearly a copy here). You could also use a [transform iterator](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_40_0/libs/iterator/doc/transform_iterator.html) here:

```
std::copy(boost::make_transform_iterator(mybimap.left.begin(), select_second()),
          boost::make_transform_iterator(mybimap.left.end(), select_second()),
          std::back_inserter(myvec));
```

where `select_second` would be a function object that selects the second element of a pair - or just the `boost::bind(&map_type::left_map::value_type::second, _1)`.

For a situation where I couldn't use a `transform_iterator` I have written a `transform_back_inserter` at work which is basically a `back_inserter` that takes an unary function that is applied to the element before writing (no rocket science to write) - then it would look like

```
std::copy(mybimap.left.begin(),
          mybimap.left.end(),
          transform_back_inserter(myvec, select_second()));
```

which I tend to prefer to the `transform_iterator` when possible as I don't have to repeat the unary function name.

Answer (score 1):

Judging from the code you posted it looks like you want to copy everything from boost::bimap to a std::vector.

Try this:

```
          std::copy(mybimap.left.begin(),
                    mybimap.left.end(),
                    std::back_inserter(myvec));
```

Comment: This does not work. I decided to use a classic for-loop to interate over the given elements.

Answer (score 0):

Try `&vector<your_value_type>::push_back` instead.